# Replace a Jquery .animate with a 0 time to something more efficient

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've recently been using this set up on a website...

http://jsfiddle.net/mnRNE/

**CSS**

```
body {
 height:2000px;   
}

#top-box {
 position:fixed;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 margin-left:100px;
 margin-top:50px;
 background-color:blue;   
 z-index:2;   
}

#bottom-box {
 position:fixed;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 margin-left:110px;
 margin-top:60px;
 background-color:red;  
 z-index:1;    

}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

 $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
        if (!away) {
            away = true;
            $('#bottom-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '200px'
            }, 1500);
        }
    } else {
        away = false;
        $('#bottom-box').stop().animate({
            'margin-top': '60px'
        }, 0);
    }
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-box"></div>
<div id="bottom-box"></div>
```

This makes it so that once the user scrolls 250 pixels down the page, the red box animates and slides out from underneath the blue box. This first animation is timed so that the transition is obvious (the red box visibly slides out).

It is then set so that if the user scrolls back above 250 pixels, the red box moves back under the blue box. This is done without a timer so the transition is instant (the red box snaps back to it's original place).

This works fine and does everything I need it to do. But I am curious as to whether there is a better way to achieve this second animation, without using an animate at all and just having the red box "reset" to "margin-top:60px" without the need to have timing or .animate?

Essentially, I am asking could the...

```
        $('#bottom-box').stop().animate({
            'margin-top': '60px'
        }, 0);
```

section of the JavaScript be written differently and more efficiently to achieve the same result but without using an animate? Like a sort of "set 'bottom-box' to 'margin-top': '60px'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using jquery [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is neater

http://jsfiddle.net/mnRNE/1/

```
        $('#bottom-box').stop().css('marginTop', '60px');
```

Does the trick

Comment: Works perfectly, it also seems to work if I put 'margin-top' instead of 'marginTop'. Is there any reason why I should use one over the other?

Comment: I thought I saw something in the CSS manual which explained this, see comment on danwellman but it was only for retrieving elements, I made the mistake of thinking it was for both setting as getting the css. So margin-top and marginTop both work fine!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#bottom-box').stop().css({ 
        'margin-top': '60px' 
    });
```

Comment: Same here, this will not work see comment on danwellman's answer.

Comment: @Tim it does work and your answer is even a duplicate of this?

Comment: This does not work. However if the { and } are removed before and after the 'margin-top': '60px' it seems to work fine.

Comment: With this you can use multiple css rules like: .css({'margin-top': '60px','display':'block'}); with this only one: .css('margin-top', '60px'); Both will work

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
$('#bottom-box').css('margin-top', '60px');
```

Comment: This will not work as Jquery prevents this from jQuery manual: Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.

Comment: This half works, in Firefox and Chome, it works as long as the first animation has finished, but if the user scrolls back up mid animation, the red-box does not reset position. If viewed in IE, Opera or Safari it seems to work fine.